# Record, modify pitch and play back audio in real time on iOS

Tags: ios, audio, audio-recording, playback

I just wondering if anyone can explain to me how I would go about recording audio, modifying it (pitch?) and playing it back to the user on iPhone.

I'm not asking for someone to do this for me, just a few hints on how I should go about it. looking through the docs it seems like I should be using `AVAudioSession`, `AVAudioRecorder` and `AVAudioPlayer` (`AVFoundation.Framework`) for the recording playing parts. Or should I be using the `CoreAudio.Framework`? and then there is the question regarding modifying the audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenAL is a library, that supports what you're searching for. And its very popular on the iPhone, so maybe you should take a look on this.
i.e. The pitch of an sample is easily changeable with only one command:

```
alSourcef(source, AL_PITCH, pitch);
```

But I'm not sure, if pitch change is also with the AVFoundation or CoreAudio classes possible - never used them.

Comment: Many thanks @Constantin I did indeed end up using openAL. Some more details can be seen at this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137853/another-question-about-recording-modifying-and-playing-audio-on-iphone

Answer (score 2):

[AVAudioUnitTimePitch](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioUnitTimePitch_Class/index.html) should do the trick.

Sample code from udacity.com [Intro to iOS App Development with Swift](https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-ios-app-development-with-swift--ud585):

```
func playAudioWithVariablePitch(pitch: Float) {
    audioEngine.stop()
    audioEngine.reset()

    let audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    audioEngine.attachNode(audioPlayerNode)

    let changePitchEffect = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()
    changePitchEffect.pitch = pitch
    audioEngine.attachNode(changePitchEffect)

    audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to:changePitchEffect, format:nil)
    audioEngine.connect(changePitchEffect, to:audioEngine.outputNode, format:nil)

    audioPlayerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime:nil, completionHandler: nil)
    try! audioEngine.start()

    audioPlayerNode.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help. [DIRAC-mobile](http://www.dspdimension.com/technology-licensing/dirac2-iphone/), a library for real-time tempo and pitch manipulation of polyphonic audio signals. They also have sample codes that you can take a look once you download the library.

Comment: thanks for the link Jinru. I'm afraid using a commercial library is not an option for me :(