# apps like talking tom and using external library for manipulating recorded sound

Tags: iphone

hello i m new in iphone i just want to know how and which libraries can be used to change the pitch of the recorded audio in iphone.Now i m using dirac library to do this if there is any other way to implement this then please help me,...thanks in advance:)

Comment: hello i m new in iphone i just want to know how and which libraries can be used to change the pitch of the recorded audio oin iphone.

Comment: Then why didn't you ask that? You posted a run on sentence, no question and no context.

Comment: Also - [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505)

Comment: sorry! i m new here.will try to keep all these things in mind .if possible please answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sebastian said, use search. People will be unwilling to help if it seems like you have asked a question without doing much research yourself thus wanting the community to provide a complete solution.

That being said I actually had the same problem a while back, check out my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137853/another-question-about-recording-modifying-and-playing-audio-on-iphone), it should provide you with enough general information in how to implement the particular solution I chose to take so that you can roll your own implementation.

Basically I recorded the audio with AVRecorder and changed the pitch, etc. with openAL. Best of luck.

[EDIT]

I just remembered this [link](http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/tutorials-how-to-change-pitch-instantenously-without-changing-tempo-like-the-talking-tom-app/). They are some tutorials for what you wish to achieve, I just wish I found them before I started doing my own implementation as it would have saved me a good bit of time. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks  i have able to change the pitch of the recorded sound by the help of dirac library.But the output sound is very noisy .if possible plz hint me to remove this.

Comment: I do not know that library sorry alok. maybe play around with the sampling rate to remove the noise.

Comment: changing of the sampling rate does not makes any visible difference in my app.!

Comment: Hey alok I updated my answer with a link to some tutorials. Hopefully that may help you achieve what you need. Best of luck!

Comment: i have gone through the links and really find myself in a condition to get started thanks a lot ....really useful.

Answer (score 1):

check out this library: http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/

or this question: [How to set pitch of an audio file or recorded audio file in iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714257/how-to-set-pitch-of-an-audio-file-or-recorded-audio-file-in-iphone-sdk)

also note: there is a search function here, AND on google :-) i just entered

`objective-c change pitch of audio` and those where the two topmost hits.

Comment: i have downloaded this library but it contains only files not any sample code about using it properly ,plz tell me how to use it.

Comment: @aloksinha: it looks like you didn't even bother to read trough the text. [Here](http://www.surina.net/article/time-and-pitch-scaling.html) are also links to sample code.

Comment: @rokjarc thanks for your answer as i m new here.but i m quite sure i will learn quickly by the help of guys like u ...thanks a lot .